# Error al insertar datos de Sqlite a Arrayadapter

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, arrayadapter

Tengo un detalle que con mi app que tengo en android studio.

El detalle es que yo obtengo tengo unos datos por medio de webservices y los almaceno en una bd local sqlite y los quiero mostrar en un listview con un adapter personalizado, el problema es cuando se hace la consulta para obtener los datos posteriormente insertarlos, al eestar haciendo la consulta me truena la app y me manda el siguiente error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
>                                                        at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
>                                                        at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
>                                                        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
>                                                        at mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrol.SqliteDB.ObtenerClientes(SqliteDB.java:95)
>                                                        at mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrol.Clientes.UpdateList(Clientes.java:293)
>                                                        at mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrol.Clientes.onCreate(Clientes.java:61)
>                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)

Les dejo código mi base de datos

```
public class SqliteDB {

    private DBhelper oBD;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public SqliteDB(Context context)
    {
        oBD = new DBhelper(context);
    }

    public void CloseDB()
    {
        if (db.isOpen())
        {
            db.close();
        }
    }

    public boolean isOpenDB()
    {
        return(db.isOpen());
    }

    public long executeSQL(String sql, Object[] bindArgs)
    {
        long iRet = 0;
        db = oBD.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(sql, bindArgs);
        CloseDB();
        return(iRet);
    }

    public Cursor querySql(String sql, String[] selectionArgs)
    {
        Cursor oRet = null;
        db = oBD.getReadableDatabase();
        oRet = db.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
        return (oRet);
    }

    private int Empresa;
    private int Cliente;
    private String ClienteClave;
    private String ClienteDescripcion;
    private int Moneda;
    private int Proveedor;
    private String ProveedorDescripcion;
    private double Saldo;
    private double SaldoVencido;
    private String DatosGenerales;


    public void insertcliente(int Empresa,
                              int Cliente,
                              String ClienteClave,
                              String ClienteDescripcion,
                              String ClienteDatosGenerales,
                              int Moneda,
                              double Saldo,
                              double SaldoVencido
    )
    {
        Object[] Data = {Empresa,Cliente,ClienteClave,ClienteDescripcion,ClienteDatosGenerales,Moneda,Saldo,SaldoVencido};
        executeSQL("INSERT INTO " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", Data );

    }

   public String [] [] ObtenerClientes()
    {
        int iCnt = 0;
        String[][] Data = null;
        String[] aFils = null;
        Cursor aRS = querySql("SELECT * FROM " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME , aFils);
        if (aRS.getCount() > 0)
        {
            Data = new String[aRS.getCount()][];
            while (aRS.moveToNext())
            {
                Data[iCnt] = new String[7];
                Data[iCnt] [0]= aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Empresa));
                Data[iCnt] [1]= aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Cliente));
                Data[iCnt] [2]= aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteClave));
                Data[iCnt] [3]= aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDescripcion));
                Data[iCnt] [4]= aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDatosGenerales));
                Data[iCnt] [5]= aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Moneda));
                Data[iCnt] [6]= aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Saldo));
                Data[iCnt] [7]= aRS.getString(aRS.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SaldoVencido));

                iCnt++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Data = new String[0][];
        }
        aRS.close();
        CloseDB();
        return (Data);
    }



    public static class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String TAG = "DBManager";
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "hugo.db";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 15;
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "ONC_Cliente";
       // public static final String _ID = "id";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Empresa = "Empresa";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Cliente = "Cliente";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ClienteClave = "ClienteClave";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDescripcion = "ClienteDescripcion";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDatosGenerales = "ClienteDatosGenerales";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Moneda = "Moneda";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_Saldo = "Saldo";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SaldoVencido = "SaldoVencido";




        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.w("[CHECK]", "DBHelper.onCreate....");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME + "("
                    + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Empresa + " INTEGER ,"
                    + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Cliente + " INTEGER ,"
                    + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteClave + "TEXT ,"
                    + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDescripcion + "TEXT ,"
                    + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_ClienteDatosGenerales + "TEXT ,"
                    + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Moneda + "INTEGER ,"
                    + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_Saldo + "DOUBLE ,"
                    + DBhelper.COLUMN_NAME_SaldoVencido + "DOUBLE "
                    + ");");

        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            Log.w(TAG, "Actualizacion de BDD de la version " + oldVersion + " a la "
                    + newVersion + ", de la que se destruira la informacion anterior");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
        DBhelper(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
    }
}

Código de adapter

 public void UpdateList() {

        String[][] aRef = oBD.ObtenerClientes();
        if (aRef != null)
        {
            ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor> arrarcliente = new ArrayList<CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor>();
            CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor cxcpSaldoClienteProveedor;

            for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < aRef.length; iCnt++){
                cxcpSaldoClienteProveedor = new CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor(ONC_SYS.NullToZeroInteger(aRef[iCnt][0]),ONC_SYS.NullToZeroInteger(aRef[iCnt][1]),aRef[iCnt][2],aRef[iCnt][3],aRef[iCnt][4],ONC_SYS.NullToZeroInteger(aRef[iCnt][5]),
                        ONC_SYS.NullToZeroDouble(aRef[iCnt][6]),ONC_SYS.NullToZeroDouble(aRef[iCnt][7]));
                arrarcliente.add(cxcpSaldoClienteProveedor);
            }
            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.clientes);
            adapterCliente = new AdapterCliente(Clientes.this,arrarcliente);
            list.setAdapter(adapterCliente);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que el problema lo esta generando tu método querySql().

```
Cursor aRS = querySql("SELECT * FROM " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME , null);
```

puedes usar simplemente `rawQuery` para obtener el cursor.

```
Cursor aRS = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DBhelper.TABLE_NAME , aFills);
```

#### Actualizacion

Revisa que en verdad `db` obtenga la instacia de la base de datos.

```
 db = oBD.getReadableDatabase();
```

Comment: ya pude solucionarlo, en gran parte tenias razon, revise el db = oBD.getReadableDatabase(); y ah iestaba fallando

Comment: Elenasys abrire otro debate por si me puedes ayudar porfas

Comment: Claro que si Hugo, con mucho gusto te ayudo.